# Show that $A_{k+2} = A_k$ for some $k$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, recurrence-relations

> $A$ is an n-tuple of nonnegative integers $(a_1,\cdots, a_n)$ so that $a_i\leq i-1$. Given any such $n$-tuple,define the successor $A' = (b_1,\cdots, b_n)$ where $b_1=0,b_{i+1}$ is the number of earlier members of $A$ that are at least $a_i$. Let $A_k$ be the sequence defined by $A_0 = A, A_{k+1}$ is the successor of $A_k$. Show that $A_{k+2} = A_k$ for some $k$.

Obviously my first opinion is to try the result for small n (e.g. $n=2,3$) and try to deduce if there's any sort of pattern. The successor of $(0,1)$ is $(0, 1).$ If there was such a $k$, then the sequence $A_k$ would be eventually periodic with period 2, but I'm not sure how that helps.

Comment: What do you mean by the "number of *earlier* members"? Are we looking at values from $a_1$ to $a_i$ only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So given a vector like
$$
A_1 = (0,0,1,3,0,0,4,4,0,2,8,7,0)
$$
we compute its successors
\begin{align*}
A_2 & = (0,1,0,0,4,5,0,1,8,3,0,1,12) \\
A_3 & = (0,0,2,3,0,0,6,3,0,3,10,6,0) \\
A_4 & = (0,1,0,0,4,5,0,2,8,3,0,2,12) \\
A_5 & = (0,0,2,3,0,0,6,2,0,3,10,5,0) \\
A_6 & = (0,1,0,0,4,5,0,3,8,2,0,2,12) \\
A_7 & = (0,0,2,3,0,0,6,2,0,4,10,5,0) \\
A_8 & = (0,1,0,0,4,5,0,3,8,1,0,2,12) \\
A_9 & = (0,0,2,3,0,0,6,2,0,5,10,4,0) \\
A_{10} & = (0,1,0,0,4,5,0,3,8,1,0,3,12) \\
A_{11} & = (0,0,2,3,0,0,6,2,0,5,10,4,0)
\end{align*}
and we notice that $A_9=A_{11}$.

The natural tool for this job is *induction* on the length of the sequence.  After proving the base case, we assume it works for length-$(n-1)$ sequences, then show it works for length-$n$ sequences.

Importantly, the coordinates of each $A_j$ are defined using only [certain terms] of $A_{j-1}$.  So we can assume by induction, for some $k$, that both $A_k$ and $A_{k+2}$ agree in the first $n-1$ coordinates.

Thus the sequences look something like this:
\begin{align*}
A_k     & = (x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_{n-1},\text{don't know}) \\
A_{k+1} & = (\text{how are the coordinates of this sequence defined?}) \\
A_{k+2} & = (x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_{n-1},\text{don't know}) \\
A_{k+3} & = (\text{how are the coordinates of this sequence defined?}).
\end{align*}
And here we argue that $A_{k+1}=A_{k+3}$.

(PS. I feel "the number of earlier members of A that are at least $a_i$" should imply $a_1$ through $a_{i-1}$.  Thus, the successor of $(0,1)$ is $(0,0)$.)

Comment: Depending on the question's interpretation, I think the answer can change. If one interprets $b_{i+1}$ to be the number of entries with index/position at most $i$ that are at least $a_{i+1}$, one gets your solution. If $b_{i+1}$ is the number of entries with index/position at most $i$  that are at least $a_i$, one gets that $(0,1)$'s successor is $(0, 1).$

Comment: If "earlier" includes $a_1$ through $a_i$, then I think the same argument works, but we add $1$ (except at the first coordinate).  But I wouldn't interpret the wording this way.